# Source Control Menu is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just installed Visual Studio Ultimate on a new computer.  It works, but there's no source control menu, and I need that.  It also doesn't check out files, not surprisingly, since I can't configure the connection to the server because the menu is missing.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's selected under `Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection`?

Comment: None.  Okay now I need to find "Perforce SCM" and install that.

Comment: Answer: I went with a 3rd party solution for integrating the two products.

Answer (score 4):

Try to right click on project in the "Solution Explorer" and click "Go Online..."

Comment: This worked for me.Several weeks ago, when I opened a project under source control to copy some code, the TF server was unreachable. Visual Studio said I would be looking at a local copy, which was fine for my purpose. Next time I loaded it, the source control section of the context menu  was missing. Following the hint above put it back.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the show...  Team Explorer suddenly disappeared for me. restarted VS to no avail.
I was able [context menu on project item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRjjb.png) to right click one of the changed files and click 'Check In'.

The check in worked,  the team explorer tab became visible and things are good. Notably, the TEAM main menu item is still missing.
My computer is a couple years old, really needs to be rebuilt. This seems to be one of those VS issues w just live with.

Hope the work around helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

View -) other windows -)Source control explorer