# Visual Studio 2017 source control missing in file menu

Tags: visual-studio-2017

As a starting developer I am running into some problemes with Visual Studio 2017. I developed some weeks without any problems, but now I can't add a project under source control.

If I add a blank solution I used to be able to add a new project to that solution, but that option isn't visible anymore. It happend when I added a project under source control. How can I undo this?

[missing menu (picture from a manual made earlier)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3AOE.png)

***Solution***: File --> Open --> Open from source control --> select the right project. 
Now new projects can be added to the solution. Save this solution and you can open it when VS starts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but see if this works. This was in visual studio 2013, but is the same problem.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783243/source-control-menu-is-missing)!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, tried that already (read the same post), but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: I've searched a bit and don't find a "good solution".. I think the best way should be uninstall and re-install Visual Studio all over again..

Comment: But before try to reset all the settings of visual studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms247075(v=vs.90)

Comment: Installing Visual Studio again would bring me in more troubles, because it would give me a new administrative number and see me as a new user...